# What is a common polarizing 50/50 beam splitter cube coating

Tags: materials, optics, thin-films

I am having problems locating references of the typical thickness and material of the coating along the hypotenuse side of 50/50 polarizing beam splitter cube.

Does anyone know what these coatings usually are? Have references or published paper references? etc.

Thanks.

Comment: google: coating on polarizing beamspiltter  - did the job. Rizea & Popescu 2011 and Macleod 2009 give some answers.

Comment: @DDuck, Thanks, using the references you provided I was able to locate the info. Unfortunately search keywords used in google do not generate identical results across users or time. Coats listed in Rizea & Popescu 2011 are TiO2 and SiO2 with BK7 glass.